# AngularJS changing {{post.title}} to Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to change the value of `{{post.title}}` in my HTML to hyperlink an URL.

Is it possible?

```
        <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
            <h2>
            {{post.title}}
                <a ng-click="editPost(post._id)" class="pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                <a ng-click="deletePost(post._id)" class="pull-right"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
            </h2>
            <em>{{post.posted}}</em>
            <p>{{post.body}}</p>
        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to ,

```
 <a ng-href="url">{{ post.title }} </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming post variable have url defined
Your h1 element data would be like this.

```
  <a ng-href="{{post.url}}">{{post.title}}</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

u can use

```
<a href="url/{{post._id}}">{{post.title}}</a>
```

as well as

```
<a ng-href="url/{{post._id}}">{{post.title}}</a>
```

Both will work but second one is appreciated. :)